# Android TextView appears blurry when scaled

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I recently found out that `TextView`s on Android are shown blurry / fuzzy when they are scaled in the **1.0**-**1.49** range.

I am not sure why this is happening, but it looks like a raster version of the unscaled version is used when the view is scaled on the XY axis in this range. However, the problem disappears if the view is scaled with a value above **1.5** (150%). Please check the attached screenshot collage in full resolution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujgmW.png

[image: scale issues]

The attached screenshots are from a real device, running Android 7.1.2 (API Level 25).

I have also tested this on an emulator running Android 9 (API Level 28), the results are identical. However, on my other device (OnePlus 6, Android 9), this issue is not present, everything scales nicely, without fuzziness.

A workaround for me was disabling HW acceleration on the current activity:

```xml
<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
```

Another workaround was setting a software layer on the parent of the view that is being scaled:

```java
((View) mScaleValueTextView.getParent()).setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Both of these will result in the `TextView` being scaled without the mentioned issue, but these methods have drawbacks, the first one that I noticed was that `TextView`'s shadow caused by the `elevation` property was not drawn.

In order to demonstrate the default behavior, I created sample app where I added a `TextView` and a `SeekBar` that controls the scale, ranging from 100% to 200%.

The view is scaled by this method:

```java
private void scaleView(View v, float scaleValue) {
    v.setScaleX(scaleValue);
    v.setScaleY(scaleValue);
}
```

You can get the entire sample app [here](https://github.com/radusalagean/android-text-view-scale-sample).

Since the same code behaves differently across devices and the issue is occurring just between the mentioned scale range, I assume this is the result of a lower-level performance optimization that may or may not be implemented on some devices.

**Is there any way to disable or work around this in a clean manner, without unwanted side effects?**

Comment: scale will stretch your view that will obviously start blur after a limit (like zooming a picture) why don't you try increasing and decreasing textSize

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammilSharif What I want to achieve in the end is something similar to [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/androidtv-adding-leanback/img/e2d0a95eca68228c.png), where a Card (or a Layout that contains multiple text views, for example), is zoomed when focused. In this case, setting the `textSize` property for each `TextView` will not be a proper solution, since the parent is already scaled.

Comment: try scaling from 50% to 100% instead of 100% to 200%, I mean design you layout for max zoom size and scale it down to actual size you want to show to user and on zoom event scale it back to 100% back, this don't blur you ui